# Using cscope on MacOS X

Tags: macos

I have downloaded cscope 15.6 on MacOSX.

But when i try launching it in MacOS Terminal or Tterm, the UP/DOWN
key does not work. I can't move it from 1 query to another in the
cscope interface.

Only CTRL-P CTRL-N works.

Can you please tell me how can I fix my problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very odd...I have cscope 15.6 installed in /usr/bin on MacOS X 10.5.7 - which means it must have come with Xcode (new machine; I don't put programs into /usr/bin except under extreme provocation).

Is there a reason not to use the Xcode version - since it works?

---

> My cscope is in $ which cscope `/opt/local/bin/cscope`; I don't even remember how I got that cscope. Can you please tell me how to uninstall that /opt/local/bin/cscope and use the one with XCode?

Well, there are a variety of possibilities.  The first step is to check whether you have /usr/bin/cscope.  Assuming yes, the next step is to look at your PATH variable, and to ensure that /usr/bin appears before /opt/local/bin.  Alternatively, you can simply remove the execute permissions on /opt/local/bin/cscope, or you can rename it, or remove it.  (Note that removing execute permissions from programs can sometimes confuse configuration scripts - I had a `/usr/gnu/bin/rm` (or some similar utility) that was non-executable on my PATH ahead of `/usr/bin/rm` and that caused some issues until I removed it.  The shells and things weren't confused; configure scripts were.

> On a related question, can you please tell me how can I configure my existing XCode project to work with Cscope? How can I build CScope database in XCode? and how can I do Cscope query in XCode?

There, I'm afraid, you're ahead of me on the learning curve...I've not yet done enough with Xcode to know the answers to those questions.  I have it installed; I've not done much, if anything, with it.  I've still got some other configuration stuff to deal with first (tedious stuff like work-mandated email client).

---

I've downloaded both 15.6 and 15.7a, and when I try to build them on Leopard (10.5.8), the configure script appears to work but the build generates the error:

```
if gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I..     -g -O2 -MT build.o -MD -MP -MF ".deps/build.Tpo" -c -o build.o build.c; \
    then mv -f ".deps/build.Tpo" ".deps/build.Po"; else rm -f ".deps/build.Tpo"; exit 1; fi
In file included from build.c:50:
/usr/include/ncurses.h:550:40: error: macro "cbreak" passed 1 arguments, but takes just 0
/usr/include/ncurses.h:575:44: error: macro "erasechar" passed 1 arguments, but takes just 0
/usr/include/ncurses.h:611:43: error: macro "killchar" passed 1 arguments, but takes just 0
make[2]: *** [build.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

This bug is also reported to the [cscope](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/) project at SourceForge by someone else, with the o/s claimed as Snow Leopard (so it is actually a problem in at least two versions - later versions of Leopard and Snow Leopard).

Comment: my cscope is in 

$ which cscope
/opt/local/bin/cscope

i don't even remember how i get that cscope.
Can you please tell me how to uninstall that /opt/local/bin/cscope and use the one with XCode?

Thank you

Comment: On a related question, can you please tell me how can I configure my existing XCode project to work with Cscope? How can I build CScope database in XCode? and how can I do Cscope query in XCode?

Thank you.

Comment: /opt/local/bin is managed by MacPorts ordinarily, so simply "port uninstall cscope".

Comment: A workaround for the /usr/include/ncurses.h related errors is now available on the cscope project at SourceForge.
You can look at http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=2906214&group_id=4664&atid=204664

Answer (score 5):

drivel solved this bug, you can look at: http://anylinux.net/post/2453.html

Apply the following patch:

```
--- src/constants.h.orig    2011-01-09 23:35:35.000000000 +0800
+++ src/constants.h 2011-01-09 23:35:55.000000000 +0800
@@ -103,7 +103,7 @@
 #define INCLUDES   8
 #define    FIELDS      9

-#if (BSD || V9) && !__NetBSD__ && !__FreeBSD__
+#if (BSD || V9) && !__NetBSD__ && !__FreeBSD__ && !__APPLE__
 # define TERMINFO  0   /* no terminfo curses */
 #else
 # define TERMINFO  1
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. If you type '?', you will get a help menu that shows that hitting ^N and ^P will move the cursor up/down.